# Attribute Setter of ActiveRecord Model is never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just wanted to override the setter of attribute "parent_id" to do some other things when the value is set.

But the setter is never called. ( The value can be retrieved as suspected, so it is obviously set by rails on another way )

How to achieve my goal?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos

  def parent_id=(value)
    puts "-----> This is never called"
    write_attribute(:parent_id, value)
  end

  def parent_id
    puts "------> This is called as suspected"
    read_attribute(:parent_id)
  end
end
```

I am new to ruby and rails and i am quite confused about those things taking me hours to get simple things done...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts/tree.rb) of `acts_as_tree`, try overriding `parent=` instead, I think the magic methods created by `ActiveRecord` use the symbol provided to `belongs_to`. Anyway, I don't know your use-case, but think about using [Active Record's filter methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) instead of overriding `ActiveRecord` methods.